# Appending list of object when querying elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi I am trying to get a query based on the following documents.

document 1

```
{
 "date" : "2021-05-19",
 "items" : [
    {
      "keyA" : "ValueA"
    }
 ]
}
```

document 2

```
{
 "date" : "2021-05-19",
 "items" : [
    {
      "keyB" : "ValueB"
    }
 ]
}
```

Output I expect

```
{
 "date" : "2021-05-19",
 "items" : [
    {
      "keyA" : "ValueA"
    },
    {
      "keyB" : "ValueB"
    }
 ]
}
```

I don't want to update this structure in ES. Only when I query, I want the result to be in this format.
Is it possible? or should I handle it after receiving the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dateagg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "date"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_keys": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "items.*"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "dateagg": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1621382400000,
          "key_as_string": "2021-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",        // note this
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_keys": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "67598919",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "keyA": "ValueA"                // note this
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "67598919",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "keyB": "ValueB"                // note this
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: But I want items object to appended to the list. Please refer the format I asked in the question.